# Order given elements with SQL ORDER BY

Tags: sql, relational-database, sql-order-by

Given:

```
  SELECT projectID, urlID, COUNT(1) AS totalClicks, projectPage,
         (SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM   tblStatSessionRoutes, tblStatSessions
           WHERE  tblStatSessionRoutes.statSessionID = tblStatSessions.ID
           AND    tblStatSessions.projectID = tblAdClicks.projectID
           AND    (tblStatSessionRoutes.leftPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage OR
                 tblStatSessionRoutes.rightPageID = tblAdClicks.projectPage)) AS totalViews
  FROM   tblAdClicks
  WHERE  projectID IN (SELECT projectID FROM tblProjects WHERE userID = 5)
  GROUP  BY projectID, urlID, projectPage
```

I need to order them so that all projects with ID = 111 come LAST in the returned data set.

So for example it might return:

```
Project ID
---------
100
100
100
156
156
143
122
111
111
111
190
154
87
```

But I need all the 111's to appear at the END of the list, without using two queries, one to select the 111's and the other to select the rest is not good enough unfortunately, as this is quite a resource intensive query.

Comment: On what basis do you want to see 111s in the end. Is it always hardcoded to 111 or is there some condition to derive this data which should come at the end?

Comment: I'm just using it as an example, the value will be replaced with a variable in my code.

Comment: ummmm, I'm telling! You used a non-royalty free image... ummm!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORDER BY
 CASE projectID WHEN 111 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
 projectID /* etc... */
```

Comment: Super thanks!  But for end of list, **THEN 1 ELSE 0** is what works :)

Comment: I spotted that... eventually ;) Or you could say "THEN 0 ELSE 1 END DESC", but that's not as clear imho.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
order by cast (projectID as integer)
```